# Dynamic Data Binding to JQGrid

Tags: database, data-binding, datatable, jqgrid-asp.net

I have JQGrid , for which I want to display the data from database which i have stored in Data Table.
How can I do that, and the column name in the JQGrid should also be dynamic, i don't want the column names in JQGrid should be hardcoded, it should take the column names from the Data Table only.
Help me out!!